# How to bind the x:Uid of a TextBlock in XAML?

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-phone-8.1, uid

I am making a menu that can display many languages so I want to set the Uid of these TextBlock on each item, how can I set the Uid of a TextBlock in XAML through data binding. Because when I set x:Uid="{Binding Label}", the IDE shows that is an error. Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the translation from strings folders you can instead of binding to the x:Uid value, bind the Text variable to a text key and use a value converter and find the translated text in code behind.

So the Xaml will look something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Label, Converter={StaticResource TranslatorConverter}}"/>
```

Then you need the value converter:

```
    public class TranslatorConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
            {
                var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse();
                return resourceLoader.GetString(((String)value)); ;            
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

The "Label" in your Resources.resw file shall then simply be without the ".text" part that you use when using the x:Uid binding.

However if the multilingual toolkit as suggested is easier or not I don´t know. I have not used the multilingual toolikt.

Answer (score 0):

The binding is used `Text="{Binding Label}"`,  when you want value to be fetched from viewmodel. Drawback you will have to handle according to language the conversion of text.
`x:Uid` is supposed to be specified inside `Strings->en_US` folder. You create a resource file by default `Resources.resw` file inside it you add `Name` lets say `Sample.Text` and its `Value` as `Your Text`.
Inside your XAMl you are supposed to use x:Uid="Sample".
Now as per your requirement when you add more language using multilingual toolkit it would handle conversion for required language and on uploading to store it would select the particular language from app package and hence user views the app in the particular language they have selected on their device.

Comment: Btw, I set the itemsource of this menu form c# code so is there any way to take it from the c# code?

Comment: Yes as I said then you will have to bind it to Text not to x:Uid but then you will have to handle it in your code behind for every language change.

Comment: Ok, I got it, but I am thinking about a method is lazier :)) But anyway, thank you.

Comment: Trust me the method one isn't lazy infact the resources method is far easy. Benefit you get all your main text converted according to language the downloaded package size reduces etc. A lot of benefits. Would suggest you to have a look before you proceed with method will help you in the long run.